# Office.context.displayLanguage is not defined in Office JS Excel Add-In Custom Functions on Windows Desktop

Tags: office-js, excel-addins

I'm trying to access the Display language of Office in my Office JS based excel add-in using Office.context.displayLanguage property (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office/office.context?view=word-js-preview#displaylanguage)

This value is accessible everywhere in Excel Online (Task Pane, Custom Functions) but in Excel Desktop only in Task Pane and not inside Custom Functions Runtime.

Is this a bug or are Common API's not available inside Custom Functions Runtime? If this is the case why is it still accessible inside Custom Functions Runtime from Excel Online?

If it is not a bug, what is the recommended way to access Common API's context properties inside Custom Functions Runtime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi this is feature is actively being worked on. Workaround if you have a taskpane visible is to fetch it from the taskpane and pass it to the Custom Function via OfficeRuntime.storage API.